How to route wireguard server traffic through a proxy?
I have two containers in my server, wireguard-server and cloudflare-warp which are deployed in the same host using:
docker run -d --name=wireguard \
  -e LANG=en \
  -e WG_HOST=example.com \
  -e PASSWORD='password' \
  -e PORT=51821 \
  -e WG_PORT=51820 \
  -e WG_MTU=1420 \
  -e WG_PERSISTENT_KEEPALIVE=20 \
  -e UI_TRAFFIC_STATS=true \
  -v /opt/wireguard:/etc/wireguard \
  --network=host \
  --cap-add=NET_ADMIN \
  --cap-add=SYS_MODULE \
  --sysctl="net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1" \
  --sysctl="net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" \
  --restart always \
  weejewel/wg-easy

and cloudflare-warp which exposes port 1080 to the host for socks5 proxy.
docker run -d \
  --name cloudflare-warp \
  --restart always \
  -p 1080:1080 \
  -e WARP_SLEEP=2 \
  --cap-add NET_ADMIN \
  --sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0 \
  --sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1 \
  -v ./data:/var/lib/cloudflare-warp \
  caomingjun/warp

I have redsocks daemon running in the host machine to redirect the connection to socks5 proxy so that I can route any apps traffic via proxy without explicitly defining my proxy settings (for example curl). The redsocks config is as follows:
base {
    log_debug = on;
    log_info = on;
    log = "file:/var/log/redsocks.log";
    daemon = on;
    redirector = iptables;
}

redsocks {
    local_ip = 127.0.0.1;
    local_port = 12345;
    ip = 127.0.0.1;
    port = 1080;
    type = socks5;
}

I can these have iptables rules to forward http/https traffic to proxy:
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 12345
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 12345

By having this, I can simply run a curl command (without mentioning proxy) and its traffic will go through the proxy.
Similarly, how can I route my traffic from wireguard server to redsocks using iptables so that all my wireguard client's traffic will go through cloudflare-warp?

Both the client/socksifier and the server needs to support UDP associate. It seems that it is not the case for either of them here.
